# Does gradient depends on the choice of an orthonormal basis?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, gradient-descent

Gradients are defined for differentiable functions $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as
the function $\nabla_f$ : $\mathbb{R}^n  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ ;
$\nabla f(p) = \begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(p) \\
 \vdots \\
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(p)
\end{bmatrix}$

I would like to see gradients as vectors in an inner product space rather than in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and wonder whether the basis as any importance as long as they are orthonormal.

To put it a little bit more formally, let $g$ be a scalar function defined over a real inner product space E. For any orthonormal basis $B$, we have a bijection $c_B$ : $E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ that transforms elements of E to their coordinates in B.
We consider the function : $\nabla'_B$ : $E \rightarrow E$ as $\nabla'_B(e)=c_b^{-1}(\nabla_{g \circ c_B^{-1}} (c_B(e))$ (i.e we transpose the definition of the gradient in $E$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$)

Does $\nabla'_B$ depends on $B$ ?
If it is the case, that would mean gradient-ascent method will behave differently depending on the choice of an orthonormal basis (as it is the case if when basis are not orthonormal).

(my work below)

Suppose that we have two different orthonormal basis $B_1$ and $B_2$ where we express the gradients $\nabla_1$ and $\nabla_2$ (vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$)

I have shown that

$\nabla_2=M^t.\nabla_1$.

(where $M$ is the transition matrix from $B_1$ to $B_2$ : columns of $M$ are the coordinates of the vectors of $B_2$ expressed in the basis $B_1$)

To express $\nabla_2$ in the basis $B_1$, I need to multiplicate it by $M$

So finally, I need to know whether $M.M^t=I$ where $M$ is transition matrix.

It seems OK for $n=2$ where $M = \begin{bmatrix} cos(\theta) \ sin(\theta) \\ sin(\theta) \ -cos(\theta) \end{bmatrix}$ But I didn't find a general proof (or counter example)

Comment: If $M$ is the transition matrix from $B_1$ to $B_2$ where $B_2$ is an orthonormal basis with respect to $B_1$, then as you point out, the columns of $M$ are the $B_1$-coordinates of the vectors in $B_2$. As the columns are orthonormal, they are all unit-length and orthogonal to each other. I think this fact can help you find the product of $M^tM$, which should help you find $MM^t$ as well.

Comment: $M^t M$ is obviously the identity. But I don't see how that can help to prove that it is also the case for $M M^t$

Comment: Let $V$ be a finite dimensional inner product space over $\mathbb R$. To say that a function $f:V \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable at $x \in V$ means that there exists a linear function $L:V \to \mathbb R$ such that the function $r:V \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x+h) = f(x) + L(h) + r(h)$ satisfies $\lim_{h \to 0} r(h)/\| h \| = 0$. It can be shown that if $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then the function $L$ is unique. It is called the derivative of $f$ at $x$. There exists a vector $g\in V$such that $L(h) = g \cdot h$ for all $h \in V$. This vector $g$ is called the gradient of $f$ at $x$.

Comment: So there is no need to mention a basis at all when defining the gradient vector.

Comment: Thank you. So definition of gradients depend only on the inner product between vectors. I obtained the result using transition matrices. But your approach is more intuitive and it is somewhat confusing to see gradients as vectors in a vector space or as elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Can you advice a good book on the subject of gradient ascents ?

Comment: In my experience many of my favorite optimization textbooks (such as Nocedal and Wright) just work in $\mathbb R^n$, but with the above viewpoint it’s not too hard to generalize the theory to the setting of a finite dimensional inner product space over $\mathbb R$. Without further information about what you’re interested in, I’d recommend Nocedal and Wright. Although you don’t need to read an entire book just to understand gradient descent.

Answer (score 1):

Transition matrices between orthonormal basis are called orthogonal matrices and they have nice properties.

Among them : $Q^t.Q=Q.Q^t=I$

more details here :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix

(Thank you Jackson for your comment that set me on the right path)

Comment: Happy to help! I think it's worth noting too that the reason $Q^t Q = I \Rightarrow Q Q^t = I$ has nothing to do with orthogonality, but simply the fact that $Q$ is square. That is, for $n \times n$ matrices over a field, right inverses and left inverses always coincide.